# Accessing Controls on page loaded in IFrame in MS CRM 4.0 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a custom aspx page loaded in a IFrame in one of the modules in MS CRM 4.0. This page basically has 6 textboxes (txtValue1, txtValue2 and so on..) with values in it. I want to access these values through javascript code either on the load event or save event. Does anybody know how to do it ? I tried couple of codes that i got from net but nothing seems to work. Any help on this would appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following snippet...

```
var textBox1Value = document.frames.IFRAME_NAME.document.all.txtValue1.value;
```

where IFRAME_NAME is the name of the IFRAME you define in the form customizations and txtValue1 is the id of the textbox on the IFRAME.

Answer (score 2):

One little gotcha that's worth noting is that accessing the iframe via the document's frames collection won't let you read or write the src or url properties that I find myself dynamically changing every now and again.  To access and change the properties, you'll need to access the iframe via `getElementById`.

```
var yourIframe = document.getElementById('IFRAME_NAME');
```

Note that if you access the iframe as above and you want to call a function that is available to the iframe's scripts, you have to call it via the contentWindow property:

```
yourIframe.contentWindow.someFuncOnIframePage();
```